# Convert simple expressions into JsonLogic format

Tags: python, pyparsing, jsonlogic

Using python, I need to convert expressions into [JsonLogic](https://jsonlogic.com) format. Expressions such as Boolean expressions, if else / ternary expressions, etc.

Any suggestions how to achieve this ?

P.S. I see that we have a `js-to-json-logic` [library](https://github.com/krismuniz/js-to-json-logic#readme) for the same in Javascript. Could not find its equivalent Python Library.

Example 1:

Input:

```
((var001 == "Y"))?1:((var001 == "N"))?0:false
```

Output:

```
{
"if": [
  {
    "==": [
      {
        "var": "var001"
      },
      "Y"
    ]
  },
  1,
  {
    "if": [
      {
        "==": [
          {
            "var": "var001"
          },
          "N"
        ]
      },
      0,
      false
    ]
  }
]
}
```

---

Example 2:

Input:

```
CustomFunc(var123, "%Y-%d", (var123 == "N" ? 0 : 123))
```

Note: Input could be a combination of custom function (having n parameters) and any of these parameters could be single attribute or a combination of further expressions.

Output:

```
{
  "CustomFunc": [
    {
      "var": "var123"
    },
    "%Y-%d",
    {
    "if": [
        {
        "==": [
                {
                    "var": "var123"
                },
                "N"
            ]
        },
        0,
        123
    ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Example 3:

Input:

```
9 + 2 - 6 * 4
```

Output as per opertor precedence and parenthesis

Comment: Be nice to try and incorporate PyParsing or more generalize sentences in the question.  While I understood the OP, it took a few rereading before I voted the question up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyparsing's infixNotation method will permit the definition of unary, binary, and ternary operators (such as your `expr ? true_value : false_value` operations).  This code will parse your given expression:

```
import pyparsing as pp
ppc = pp.common

bool_constant = pp.oneOf("true false")
integer = ppc.integer()
ident = ppc.identifier()
qs = pp.quotedString()

operand = qs | integer | bool_constant | ident

comparison_operator = pp.oneOf("< > >= <=")
eq_operator = pp.oneOf("== !=")

expr = pp.infixNotation(operand,
                        [
                            (comparison_operator, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
                            (eq_operator, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
                            (('?', ':'), 3, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
                        ])

expr.runTests("""\
                ((var001 == "Y"))?1:((var001 == "N"))?0:false
                """
              )
```

Having the parser is the first half of the battle. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64709299/pyparsing-evaluating-expression/64819830#64819830) continues on to show how to attach classes to the various parsed terms - in that case it was to evaluate the result, but for you, you'll probably want to do something like implement a `as_jsonlogic()` method to these classes to emit equivalent forms for the JsonLogic format.

EDIT:

Ok, that may not have been that helpful to just show you the parser. So here is the parser with the added classes, and their respective as_jsonlogic() methods.

```
import pyparsing as pp
ppc = pp.common

bool_constant = pp.oneOf("true false")
integer = ppc.integer()
ident = ppc.identifier()
qs = pp.quotedString()

class Node:
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self._tokens = tokens
        self.assign_vars()

    def assign_vars(self):
        pass

    def as_jsonlogic(self) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Verbatim(Node):
    def as_jsonlogic(self) -> str:
        return str(self._tokens[0])

class Identifier(Node):
    def as_jsonlogic(self) -> str:
        return f'{{ "var": "{self._tokens[0]}" }}'

class Comparison(Node):
    def assign_vars(self):
        self.oper1, self.operator, self.oper2 = self._tokens[0]

    def as_jsonlogic(self) -> str:
        return f'{{ "{self.operator}" : [ {self.oper1.as_jsonlogic()}, {self.oper2.as_jsonlogic()} ]  }}'

class Ternary(Node):
    def assign_vars(self):
        self.condition, _, self.true_value, _, self.false_value = self._tokens[0]

    def as_jsonlogic(self) -> str:
        return f'{{ "if" : [ {self.condition.as_jsonlogic()}, {self.true_value.as_jsonlogic()}, {self.false_value.as_jsonlogic()} ]  }}'

# add the classes a parse actions, so that each expression gets converted to a Node subclass instance
qs.add_parse_action(Verbatim)
integer.add_parse_action(Verbatim)
bool_constant.add_parse_action(Verbatim)
ident.add_parse_action(Identifier)

operand = qs | integer | bool_constant | ident

comparison_operator = pp.oneOf("< > >= <=")
eq_operator = pp.oneOf("== !=")

# add parse actions to each level of the infixNotation    
expr = pp.infixNotation(operand,
                        [
                            (comparison_operator, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, Comparison),
                            (eq_operator, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, Comparison),
                            (('?', ':'), 3, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, Ternary),
                        ])

# use runTests to run some tests, with a post_parse function
# to call as_jsonlogic() on the parsed result
expr.runTests("""\
    "Y"
    false
    100
    var001
    (var001 == 100)
    ((var001 == "Y"))?1:((var001 == "N"))?0:false
    """, post_parse=lambda s, r: r[0].as_jsonlogic())
```

Prints:

```
"Y"
"Y"

false
false

100
100

var001
{ "var": "var001" }

(var001 == 100)
{ "==" : [ { "var": "var001" }, 100 ]  }

((var001 == "Y"))?1:((var001 == "N"))?0:false
{ "if" : [ { "==" : [ { "var": "var001" }, "Y" ]  }, 1, { "if" : [ { "==" : [ { "var": "var001" }, "N" ]  }, 0, false ]  } ]  }
```

I'll leave the pretty indentation to you.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. Appreciate the efforts of providing complete answer. It helped a lot since I am new in Python and was struggling with coming with correct precedence and right way of doing it.

Comment: I have added two more examples, example2 contains custom function having n parameters and example3 contains multiple operators. In example3, I am getting error "too many values to unpack". Any idea what modifications could be made in grammar to accommodate these cases ?

Comment: This topic is already covered in other answers I and others have posted here on SO, and in the pyparsing examples.

Comment: This is still useful examples.  ALthough, the question could be clarified a bit further to leverage this answer.